# How to specify __init__.py while building a python library

Tags: python-3.x

This is the first python library I am building. The folder structure looks like:

```
mylibrary
    - build
    - data
    - docs
    - environment.yml
    - README.md
    - license
    - setup.py

    - my library
        - __init__.py

        - Module1
          - __init__.py
          - module1_worklfow.py

        - Module 2
          - __init__.py
          - module2_worklfow.py
```

On the init.py under "mylibrary" I have the statement `from .Module1 import classfrommodule1workflow` and  `from .Module2 import classfrommodule2workflow`.

On the `__init__` files that are inside the modules, I have `from mylibrary.module1.module1_workflow import classfrommodule1workflow` and the same for module2 init.

Now if I install the library through the conda command line with wheel, the library imports well. I am able to run in python `from mylibrary import module1` but then if in the same command line I open a jupyter notebook, I am not able to import the library within jupyter. It says - `no module named mylibrary.module1`

I'm almost sure there's something wrong with my main init file, just can't figure out what it is.

EDIT: folder with files for MCVE [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Y6ucdLRZVtGjIC3uj57cX4oMBQcTNYIG?usp=sharing).

Steps on anaconda prompt:

```
cd folder_path
conda env create -f environment.yml
conda activate mylibrary
python setup.py bdist_wheel
pip install path_to_wheel
python

import mylibrary
import mylibrary.module1
quit()
```

This won't throw any errors, which is great! Then on the same command line:
jupyter notebook

then on the jupyter notebook:

```
import mylibrary
```

yields:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8c582ad816fa>     in     <module>
    ----> 1 import mylibrary

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mylibrary'
```

and

```
import mylibrary.module1
```

yields:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-64d831ac2965> in <module>
----> 1 import mylibrary.module1

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mylibrary'
```

Here's an image for clarity:

[image]

Comment: Please show an actual MCVE and full error with stack trace.

Comment: @MadPhysicist edited per your suggestions

Comment: Are you using the anaconda environment in the jupyter notebook?

Comment: @Monolith, I'd say so... I'm launching the notebook from within the environment I've installed my library. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit:

OK, I downloaded your code and it seems to be an issue with your `setup.py` after all. You forgot to add `packages=find_packages(),` to the argument list of `setup`, so the package you were installing was effectively empty. When `import mylibrary` was working for you when launching `python` from command line, it was probably because `import` also loads modules from current directory (try launching `python` from a different directory and check if it works).

By the way, you don't have to build a wheel if you just want to install from source. You can use `pip install .` or `python setup.py install`. Alternatively, for development purposes it's useful to do `pip install --editable .` or `python setup.py develop`.

---

#### Original answer:

Sounds like your package/library is OK but when you're launching `jupyter notebook` it's probably using a different interpreter. It should help to install `jupyter` in the conda environment. If it still doesn't work, you can try launching it with `python -m jupyter notebook` to ensure that you're using the same interpreter as for installing your package.

Comment: Thanks for the suggest @Czaporka. Will use the commands for installation. Re. jupyter, on `mylibrary` environment I can see that mylibrary and jupyter are installed. Doing  `python -m jupyter notebook` from within the environment still didn't do the trick, still the same error...

Comment: @LaCordillera I've edited the answer, please check.

Comment: it worked, @Czaporka! Thanks for the suggestion. Is there any reference for best practice on building libraries - just like this advice you just gave me, besides the documentation?

Comment: [The official tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) is quite good. Other than this, I don't really know, but it really isn't that complicated. You can always go to GitHub and view how some popular projects are configured. Also one more tip: in situations similar to this one (when you've installed your package and some stuff seems to be missing), you can unzip the package file and check what's inside (a .whl file is actually a .zip file in disguise). In this particular case you would notice your modules are not there so you would know what to google.